# Control + F5 is giving 403 forbidden error for some images randomly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-403

I have an application build in MVC and deployed on the IIS(6.2).
The page is load with all the images but when I press Ctrl + F5, some images randomly gives 403 Forbidden error and image stop showing. But when I copy image source and access it from the other browser tab, it shows the image.

I already check for permission on the image folder and it is as expected with all the required permission.

When I do only F5 to reload with the browser button, it loads all the images as expected.

Images should load properly with Ctrl + F5 as well.

What can be the possible reasons and its fixes?

**

> Answer: I have resolved the issue. Please see my last comment for the
>   solution.

**

Comment: Do you have img elements pointing directly to the files, or something more complicated? What if you refresh the browser window?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, Yes, Image elements are pointing directly to the files. If I do just F5, the browser loads all images as expected.

Comment: I found the exact issue and solved it. I am posting the answer in case it would be helpful to someone. By enabling the details error and logs I come to know the subcode of the 403 error. It is 403.502 HTTP error code which means the request was denied due to the concurrent requests restriction and number of request in specific time restriction from one IP address. This setting is inside the "IP Address and Domain Restriction" in IIS. Here is the link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions[link] which explain complete settings.

Comment: FYI: you *are* allowed to answer your own question, especially if you can add details that might help someone else

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on a windows plesk hosted website : 403 errors on images and js files when hard refreshing the web page (ctrl + f5)

Thanks to your last comment, I went to the Windows server to check the IIS settings. You can follow this steps to solve the problem :

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
2. Click on your connection in the left panel
3. Double click on "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" in the IIS central tab
4. Click on "Edit Dynamic Restriction Settings..." in the right panel (Actions)
5. Uncheck the checkboxes or increase the value if needed.
6. Click on "ok"

That's it.

Hope it helps !